# sklearn RFE with GaussianProcessClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working with a recursive feature elimination ([RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html)) pipeline:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

c_GAUSS = GaussianProcessClassifier()
rfe = RFE(estimator=c_GAUSS)
```

However, I get an error:

```
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying 
estimator GaussianProcessClassifier should have `coef_` or 
`feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to 
feature selector or call fit before calling transform.
```

With SVC, I just solved this problem by putting a coefficient in the SVC with `c_SVC = SVC(C = 1)`.

Is there any possible workaround here, since GPC doesn't have coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's not. As the [documentation of RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) states, the estimator is expected "to assign weights to features". A compatible estimator has to expose those weights either through the `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Have a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py#L44) of RFE, it's pretty straightforward.

I'm not very familiar with `GaussianProcessClassifier`, however, it seems that this type of classifier does not perform any feature scoring. If you think that there's a natural way to score features for a GPC after training, you could extend the `GaussianProcessClassifier` yourself:

```py
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
class WeightedGaussianProcessClassifier(GaussianProcessClassifier):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        super().fit(X,y)
        # Implement here your weight
        self.feature_importances_ = ...
        return self
check_estimator(WeightedGaussianProcessClassifier)
```

Follow the instructions [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html) on how to develop your own estimator. This way, you make the estimator compatible with the `RFE` class.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [RFE documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html), the estimator requires information about feature importances (e.g. `estimator.coef_`, `estimator.feature_importances_`). Unfortunately, the GPC estimator does not come with this attribute, due to the way classification is done in GPs.

According to an answer on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149112/how-to-compare-the-relative-importance-of-features-in-gp-regression), one approach to determine feature importance in GP classification would be to determine the classification error or other metric you're using by successively leaving out one feature at a time. This is time-intensive and not done by the GP by default. However, this would require implementing your own RFE function (not too difficult).